# Prevent an iframe from reloading everytime page is changed with PHP

Tags: php, html, iframe, phpbb

I currently have what I believe to be a dynamic page, using the following PHP code to serve up my pages (URL looks like web.site/index.php?page=***)

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['page']) || empty($_GET['page'])) {
$_GET['page']="home";
}
$maxreg = 2;
$min = 0;   
$page = $_GET['page'];
$pages = array('home', 'about', 'photos', 'contact', 'forum');
if (!empty($page)) {
if(in_array($page,$pages)) {
    $page .= '.php';
    include($page);
}
else {
echo 'Page not found. Return to
<a href="index.php">home</a>';
}
}
?>
```

Which works quite splendidly. However I've recently started trying to get a bit more "tricky" with my page, and have included an iFrame that points to the chat module 'mChat' from my phpBB forum.

```
<div style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 201, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 100%; max-height=400px;">


<iframe scrolling="no" src="/forum/app.php/mchat" style="border: 0px none; height: 859px; margin-right: -50px; margin-top: -400px; width: 100%;">
</iframe>

</div>
```

Although I know this isn't the best way of achieving this goal, I couldn't get mChat to display on an external page any other way and had to settle for an iFrame, and it looks like with a bit more CSS trickery it'll be perfect, but I've encountered an issue. If I move from say '?page=home' on my website to '?page=about', then the iFrame reloads as well, even though it's embeded as apart of index.php. I spent a lot of time googling the matter and going through stackoverflow, but came up short for an answer.

Is what I'm trying to do a limiation of PHP? Is it something like my site isn't acutally "dynamic" and just rebuilds it each time from a cache or something? Or is there a trick here I could implement to make the iframe "dynamic" throughout the rest of my site?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Not sure there is anything you can do. If you are navigating to a different page, the browser will have t ping the server for the resources it needs, including reload of the chat. Aside from a Single Page App (SPA), or rather , maintaining the window.location() as a singular source.

Comment: Hmm I was worried this might be the case. Perhaps then, would you possible know, if I use a bit of jquery or javascript (or maybe even modify the css directly, I do have access to the contents of the iframe), to remove the hidden header and footer, and then set the iframe to load first, that perhaps this might have my desired effect? To try and ask this clearer I mean does the "tricks" for stripping away elements out of an iFrame in fact stop those elements being rendered and loaded, or does it still load everything (so any larger banners in a header for example), and then just hide them? ty!!

Comment: Ended up converting my page to jquery and ajax to achieve this. Only drama now is my submit post to forum externally isn't working. Gonna open a different question thread to try and get some aid there.